# If a quantum particle has a range of possible locations, why does it end up where we want to observe it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

Quantum theory says that a particle could be anywhere in particular space, we only have a probability of where it will be, but when we observe it, we have a fixed value. But why does it end up near the sensor, why doesn't it just end up somewhere else and is not observed at all?

Comment: Well, yeah, sometimes that happens. The detector might not click. When it does, the quanta ends up near it.

Comment: If you have observed it, well, it was in your experimental apparatus. If you don't observe it, well, maybe it was there and maybe it wasn't. (Of course, the observation could just have been noise or a cosmic ray strike on the electronics).

Answer (score 1):

Well, usually you have a measurement that works on the whole space at once. For instance, you would flash a laser at an atom and wait to get a reflection back. The location of the reflection gives you the atomic position. However, you're right that *in general* there's no need for measurement to work like that. It might be possible to get a negative result. Imagine that the particle can be in one of $N$ boxes, and all you get to do is open one. In this case, a negative result is still a result, and the particle doesn't collapse to being in one place, but it does collapse the wavefunction onto the other $N-1$ boxes.

In other words, if it ends up not being in the place you looked, that's still a measurement. It just doesn't tell you quite as much as actually finding a particle.

Answer (score 0):

> But why does it end up near the sensor, why doesn't it just end up somewhere else and is not observed at all?

If fact it does end up elsewhere. When so, if the observer is located at $x$, they do not observe the particle at $x$, the detector does not detect the particle and the result of the experiment is that the particle state has collapsed into another eigenket of the position operator $|x'\rangle^1$ located elsewhere in the universe. An example of such is the [double slit experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment).

---

$^1$ There are no eigenstates of the position operator, but that's another matter.

Comment: but in the double slit experiment, it is observed that the particle passes through either one of the slits every time, why doesn't it go somewhere else?

Comment: @Learn_to_forget In the double slit experiment the system is made of only two possible eigenstates of the position: $|x_L\rangle$ and  $|x_R\rangle$ as it is constrained so. If one performs measurements on each single slit one sees that the electron *always* goes either left or right, therefore at any measurement there's always an eigenstate of the position operator in the system into which the electron state collapses.

Comment: so as time goes one, these possible locations increase?

Comment: Why would they increase?